# I need my user to be able to write the name of a planet, and have the program take that variable name and store it with a value

Tags: python-2.x

I am making a game with randomized planets and I want the program to:
1. Allow the user to name the planet
2. Take the name the user wrote and add it to a list of planets
3. Have this new variable contain the value of another variable called "CurrentPlanet" (CurrentPlanet is a variable containing planet stats. I already made that variable!)

The main problem is, I have no idea how to create a dictionary to hold all the planets the user has visited.

Here's my code:

```
print "Planet analysis complete."

planetName = (raw_input('Please name the planet: '))

inputPlanet = planetName

vars()[planetName] = CurrentPlanet

print inputPlanet 
print CurrentPlanet
```

What I want the UI to look like after this is:

```
Please name the planet: Alpha32
You've named your current planet "Alpha32". 
Its stats are (stats, etcetcetcetcetcetc)
Planet "Alpha32" added to log, number (planet number on list of visited planets)
```

Comment: what language are you writing in ?

Comment: Your tags are useless. The most important thing to tag is the language you're working in.

Comment: I'm going to add a Python2 tag given your `print`s aren't normal functions.

Comment: Sheesh, sorry guys. I'm new. Also didn't know this site was like, weird about potty words.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple

```
planets = []
stats = {} # dictionary
planetName = raw_input("Please name the planet: ")
print ("You've named your current planet " + planetName + ".")
planets.append(planetName)

print planets
```

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure what you wanted for the dictionary but they take 2 things the key and value for example... dictionary = { key: value } if this is the answer then choose it as the answer and to learn python you can use codecademy

Comment: Ok, so now, how do I allow the user to choose the planet they want from this dictionary and view its stats?

Comment: As in: how do I display the value of a key?

Comment: You would do print stats[1]